# "TypeError: localStorage is null.." if dom.storage.enabled==false in firefox

Tags: bug, status-completed, browser-support

In my Firefox browser, I have the config option dom.storage.enabled disabled. This normally isn't a problem, but on some StackExchange pages (https://serverfault.com/, https://security.stackexchange.com/, and here on https://meta.stackoverflow.com/), I can't post new questions, pressing the "post" button only reloads the page. Also, the wysiwyg preview doesn't show up and error messages are not shown. I tracked the problem down to a `TypeError: localStorage is null..` javascript error (found using FireBug).

I think StackExchange should also work if such browser features are disabled or missing...

Comment: Oh, I wanted to post this message on http://meta.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It's a duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/218547/tag-editing-broken-if-localstorage-is-disabled

Comment: reproduced, on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed in next build (build rev `2015.2.13.3072` on meta, `2015.2.13.2295` on sites).